# A simple chatterbot using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, performance, chat

I'm wrote a basic chatterbot. What would you do to pretty much improve it and make it better than this?

Because I want this chatterbot to be the best it could be, and I really want other peoples' opinion of how they would improve it. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk  

# --- functions ---

def cmd3():
    # default value at start
    x = None
    y = None
    
    # remove previous text
    label1['text'] = ""
    label2['text'] = ""
    
    text = text1.get()
    
    if text == "":
        label1['text'] = "Statement"
    elif text == "Hello":
        x = "Hello"
    elif text == "Goodbye":
        x = "Goodbye"
    elif text == "Hi":
        x = "Hello"
    else:
        label1['text'] = "Please enter a valid statement"

    text = text2.get()
     
    if text == "":
        label2['text'] = "Question"
    elif text == "How are You?":
        y = "I'm going good"
    elif text == "What is your name?":
        y = "I'm Turing"
    elif text == "When did your Creator start working on you?":
        y = "In the year 2022"
    elif text == "Do you like Star Wars?":
        y = "Yes, I was actually inspired by the personallities from droids from Star Wars."
    else:
        label2['text'] = "please enter a valid question"
        
    print(x, y)


    if (x is not None) and (y is not None):
        label_result['text'] = str(x + " " + y)

# --- main ---

new = tk.Tk()


label1 = tk.Label(new, text="", fg="red")
label1.pack()

text1 = tk.Entry(new, width="60")  
text1.pack()


label2 = tk.Label(new, text="", fg="red")
label2.pack()

text2 = tk.Entry(new, width="60")  
text2.pack()
        
btn3 = tk.Button(new, text="Enter", command=cmd3)
btn3.pack()   


label_result = tk.Label(new, text="", fg="green")
label_result.pack()

new.mainloop()
```

Comment: *chatterbot* = *[chatbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatbot)*

Answer (score 3):

`cmd3` is not a very good function name. Consider instead something like `on_enter`.

`x + " " + y` does not need a `str()`.

Consider writing a single response dictionary instead of multiple `if` statements.

I don't find your user interface to be very natural. An easy and intuitive interface for a chat bot would be a single `Text` widget that responds on each line.

You should probably ignore case when checking user questions.

### Suggested

```py
import tkinter as tk

RESPONSES = {
    "how are you?":
        "I'm going good",
    "what is your name?":
        "I'm Turing",
    "when did your creator start working on you?":
        "In the year 2022",
    "do you like star wars?":
        "Yes, I was actually inspired by the personalities from droids from Star Wars."
}


def setup(root: tk.Tk) -> None:
    def keyup(event: tk.Event):
        if event.keysym != 'Return':
            return

        nonlocal text
        line = text.get('end -2 lines', 'end').strip().lower()
        response = RESPONSES.get(line, 'Please enter a valid statement')
        text.insert('end', response + '\n', 'response')

    text = tk.Text(root)
    text.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    text.tag_configure('response', foreground='green')
    text.bind('<KeyRelease>', keyup)


def main() -> None:
    root = tk.Tk()
    setup(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

[image: example run]